# Half closed interval and open interval

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to prove if $f: [a,b) \to (a,b)$ is surjective, then $f$ is not strictly increasing or decreasing. My attempt was suppose $f$ is strictly monotone, and wlog, assume for every $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$. But then I'm not sure this contradict with surjectivity?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. You'll increase your chances of getting help in this forum (many users won't even read your question if it's not properly formatted).

Comment: Hint: if $f$ is strictly monotone, what is $f(a)$?

Comment: I do not think you mean specific value of $f(a)$ right? or do you mean how us $f(a)$ related to other points?

Comment: Think about how it relates to other points in $(a,b)$. Surjectivity is key here

Comment: Here's a little more to go on. Set c=f(a), so c is in (a,b). Since the interval is open, there exists d<c with d in (a,b). Now what?

Comment: mhmm does it mean f(a) would not be the smallest? but a is the smallest in [a,b) so we reach a contradiction?

Comment: Exactly, you got it!

Comment: thank you so much!